# Milking Cows (USACO) : Wrong result in large input test case

Tags: java, algorithm

I am doing the Milking Cows problem from USACO training

> Three farmers rise at 5 am each morning and head for the barn to milk three cows. The first farmer begins milking his cow at time 300 (measured in seconds after 5 am) and ends at time 1000. The second farmer begins at time 700 and ends at time 1200. The third farmer begins at time 1500 and ends at time 2100. The longest continuous time during which at least one farmer was milking a cow was 900 seconds (from 300 to 1200). The longest time no milking was done, between the beginning and the ending of all milking, was 300 seconds (1500 minus 1200).
>
> Your job is to write a program that will examine a list of beginning
>   and ending times for N (1 <= N <= 5000) farmers milking N cows and
>   compute (in seconds):
>
> The longest time interval at least one cow was milked. The longest
>   time interval (after milking starts) during which no cows were being
>   milked.

I am trying a direct approach after saving the inputs in a TreeMap so as to sort by the starting time

```
i1 = tm.firstKey();// first key - tm is the treemap with values sorted by starting time
    i2 = tm.get(tm.firstKey());// firstvalue
        longest_conti = i2 - i1;
        x=i2;
 // to find longest time interval at least one cow was milked.
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> m : tm.entrySet()) {

            i3 = m.getKey();
            i4 = m.getValue();
            t = i4 - i3; // a farmers time interval
            if (t >= longest_conti))
            longest_conti = t;
            if(i3>x)
            {
                i1=i3;
                x=i4;
            }
                else
                {longest_conti = longest_conti > (i4 - i1) ? longest_conti : (i4 - i1);
                x=i4>x?i4:x;
                }


            System.out.println(longest_conti); 
        }
// to find the  longest time interval in which no cows were being milked
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> m : tm.entrySet()) {

            i3 = m.getKey();
            i4 = m.getValue();

            if (i3 > i2) {
                longest_no = longest_no > (i3 - i2) ? longest_no : (i3 - i2);   
            } 
            if(i2<i4)
            i2=i4;

    }
```

I am getting the right answer for first 7 test case but the 8th test case with 5000 inputs is failing ( that too only in finding the longest interval , that is why i have separated finding the two intervals ) . Can anyone explain where i am erring ( Please help me explain the error in my code before giving your solution ) .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: The code you've posted is very hard to read. I'd recommend to format it properly and give variables more meaningful names if you want to get help.

Comment: @kraskevich I've made a few changes ... please have look again . Others are temp variables just to hold values .

Comment: @JoeC I have already dry run the program on smaller test cases and not able to find any issues . The test compiler is accepting all test cases except one with 5000 values . As a last resort I came to SO for communities help . PS. I dont know how to use debugging tools .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TreeMap then check for duplicate key before inserting into TreeMap because TreeMap will silently override previous Key-Value pair. Your test cases might be having duplicate starting times, you should check the end time (more specifically time interval of milking) and based on that write your logic.

Comment: Thanks ,,, worked like a charm .